# How do I check if a City already exists in a MySQL database?

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying to set up an exception where if a user enters a city that already exists in my database, then they get a message stating the city already exists.

I have database connections set up in a class called Database. Here is my code:

```cs
try
{
    string doesCityExist = ($"SELECT * FROM city WHERE city = ('{cityTxtBox.Text}')");
    if (doesCityExist != "")
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("City already exists");
    }

    if (cityTxtBox.Text == "")
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("City name must be filled in.");
    }                
    else
    {
        coID = Convert.ToInt32(idTxtBox.Text);                    
        cID = Database.addCity(cName, coID, InterfaceScreen.ActiveUser.UserName);
    }

    Close();
}
catch (ApplicationException error)
{
    MessageBox.Show(error.Message, "Instructions", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
}
catch (Exception err)
{
    MessageBox.Show(err.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
}
```

---

**Moved from self-answer post:**

Here is my database class which includes a query to INSERT the created city into MySQL database:

```cs
public static int addCity(string cName, int countryID, string username)
{
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    var addedCity = new City(cName, countryID, now, username, now, username);
                            
    dbc.Open();
                
    string report = $"INSERT INTO `city` VALUES ({addedCity.CityId}, '{addedCity.CityName}'," +
                    $"'{addedCity.CountryId}'," +
                    $"'{addedCity.CreateDate.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)}'," +
                    $"'{addedCity.CreatedBy}', '{addedCity.LastUpdate.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)}'," +
                    $"'{addedCity.LastUpdateBy}')";
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(report, dbc);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    dbc.Close();
    CustomerScreen.CityDictionary.Add(addedCity.CityId, addedCity);
    return addedCity.CityId;
}
```

This class also holds my database connection code:

```cs
private static string connectionStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySQLConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

private static MySqlConnection dbc = new MySqlConnection(connectionStr);
```

Should I add it into the `addCity` before my INSERT code? If so, how would that look without the `Using (idbConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Your Database Connection String"))`?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing some database access code.

Using [Dapper](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper), your query would look something like this:

```
using (IdbConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Your Database Connection String"))
{
    string sql = @"SELECT * from Cities where City = @City";

    var result = conn.QueryFirstOrDefault(sql, new { City = myCity });

    if (result != null)
    {
        // City already exists
    }
}
```

Where the name of your Cities table is `Cities`, and the name of your column is `City`.